# shell scripting that uses sudo su - team and perform rest command under this sudo access only

Tags: linux, shell, sqlplus, sudo, su

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo su - team  //// this will change user to team
<somecommnand>
```

here i have some command like sqlplus that run under this privilege only .

but ,this script first asked for password then i give password but it not run rest of command like  .

How to write script that use sudo su and run  all command in script below it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could try having all of the commands on the same line and seperate them with ';'.

eg.  'sudo su; somecommand; another command'

Could also run that script as the intended user.

Comment: That wouldn't work at all. `somecommand` would only execute *after* `sudo` exits.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options.

1. You can just move the `sudo` command outside of your script, and have people call it like this:

   ```
   sudo -u team /path/to/your/script
   ```
2. You can put the `sudo` command in one script and the actual commands you want to run with elevated privileges in another script.  That is, people run `your_script`, which looks like:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sudo -u team /path/to/your_script.real
   ```

   And `your_script.real` contains the commands that you want to run with elevated privileges.
3. If you really want everything in the same script and you don't mind being a little too clever, you can have the script check re-execute itself using `sudo` like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   TEAM_UID=500 # replace with correct uid

   if [ "$UID" != $TEAM_UID ]; then
       exec sudo -u team $0
   fi
   ```
4. And you can also feed commands to a shell from *stdin*, like this:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh
   sudo su - team <<'EOF'
   echo my uid is $UID
   EOF
   ```

Comment: i have to do following things through only script:
1>swith to user team;
2> 1st result  to /home/team(sid1)
3> then i have to go team h 
4> then sqlplus commnad will work

Comment: And the answer you've accepted will not do that.  One of the options presented here will, but you are certainly under no obligation to believe me!  Good luck.

Comment: can you please favor me only one thing

#!/bin/bash
sudo su - vapo 
<command>
<commnad>

this script asked for password ,after providing password it will also run commands below it